# color should set both facecolor and edgecolor in pyplot.bar

Tags: matplotlib

In pyplot.bar, should the color keyword argument not be a shortcut to set both facecolor and edgecolor ? It does not seem to work this way. It seems to be equivalent to facecolor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is indeed a little ambiguous (color is "[the color of the bars](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar)"), and the edge color is indeed not set by the `color` keyword:

```
>>> bar_plot = bar(range(3), range(3), color='r')  # Red
>>> rect0 = bar_plot.patches[0]  # First bar
>>> rect0.get_facecolor()  # Red!
(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
>>> rect0.get_edgecolor()  # Black!
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

This is, as you note, inconsistent with [set_color](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html?highlight=set_color#matplotlib.collections.Collection.set_color), which sets both the edge and the face color.

You can report this through the Matplotlib bug report system, but changing this behavior would change the behavior of existing programs, so fixing the inconsistency would have a serious drawback (unfortunately).

Comment: It seems wrong because of the documentation of set_color for a collection or a patch or a spine or anything that has both face and edge : [link]http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html?highlight=set_color#matplotlib.collections.Collection.set_color

Comment: Good point. I updated the answer—"answer" is a big word, as my answer is mostly contained in your question. :)

Comment: OK, thanks. I have reported the issue in Matplotlib Github tracker. [link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2218).